# How Get property of selected Polygons in Open Layers?

Tags: openlayers

I have store some polygon vertices in database, within loading there from db and drawing on map, I set a property on each of them:

```
for (let index = 0; index < msg.payload[0].missionCoords.length; index++) {
            const missionCoords = msg.payload[0].missionCoords[index];
            const polygonCoords = [];
            missionCoords.forEach(element => {
                polygonCoords.push(ol.proj.transform(element, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
            });



            const polygon = new ol.geom.Polygon([polygonCoords]);
            
            const polygonFeature = new ol.Feature({
                geometry: polygon,
            });

            polygonFeature.setProperties({
                'index': index
            })

            polygonLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: new ol.source.Vector({
                    features: [polygonFeature],
                    // wrapx: false
                }),
                style: function(feature) {
                    return styleFunction(feature, showSegments.checked)
                }
            });

            map.addLayer(polygonLayer);
            polygonSelect = new ol.interaction.Select({
                layers: [polygonLayer]
                // wrapx: false 
            });

            const polygonModify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
                features: polygonSelect.getFeatures()
            });
            map.addInteraction(polygonSelect);
            map.addInteraction(polygonModify);}
```

I need index property that I want assign them beacause I want update them after modification. Anyway, How I can get that propertice of selected polygon after clicking on a bottom. I used `polygonLayer.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getProperties()` but I get the last added polygon on map (with and without any polygon select). I also used `polygonSelect.getProperties()` and I get nothing.

Comment: If you want the properties of the selected feature `polygonSelect.getFeatures().getArray()[0].getProperties()`

Comment: Thanks, It's worked.